# Authentication listeners when refactoring to React hooks

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to change my authentication handling component when refactoring from a React class to React hooks.

Here's the relavant code in my **class**:

```
  state = {
    user: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    authGetUser(user => {
      if (user !== this.state.user) {
        this.setState({user})
      }
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

    authUnsubscribe()
  }

  handleAuthClick = () => {

    if (this.state.user) {
      authSignOut()
    } else {
      authSignIn()
    }
  }
```

And here it is with **hooks**:

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState<firebase.User | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    return authUnsubscribe() // runs on mount and unmount only
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    authGetUser(usr => setUser(usr))
  }, [])

  const handleAuthClick = () => {

    if (user) {
      authSignOut()
    } else {
      authSignIn()
    }
  }
```

Also, here are my other relevant methods:

```
const authGetUser = (callback: (user: firebase.User | null) => void) => {

  initFirebase()
  authUnsubscribe()
  userUnsubscribe = firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(callback)
}

export const authUnsubscribe = () => {

  if (userUnsubscribe) {
    userUnsubscribe()
  }
}

const authSignIn = () => {

  googleAuth.signIn().then((googleUser: any) => {

    var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token)

    firebaseAuth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
  })
}

const authSignOut = () => {

  googleAuth
  .signOut()
  .then(firebaseAuth.signOut())
}
```

Both examples work. However, when I log out and log in with the hooks version, I get an error message in console saying

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
```

which suggests that the cleanup is not done properly.

Yes, I know I could just continue using the version with the class which works. But I want to understand React hooks better by solving this.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are invoking `authUnsubscribe` directly in the first `useEffect`, but you want to return a function that should be run on unmount. `useEffect(() => authUnsubscribe, [])`

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It still works the same, including the error message in the console...

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this works for you? You could use a single `useEffect()`.

[React Hooks API DOCs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    const subscription = props.source.subscribe();
    return () => {
      // Clean up the subscription
      setUser(null); // <--- TRY DOING SOMETHING LIKE THIS
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  },
  [],
);
```

> The clean-up function runs before the component is removed from the UI
>   to prevent memory leaks. Additionally, if a component renders multiple
>   times (as they typically do), the previous effect is cleaned up before
>   executing the next effect. In our example, this means a new
>   subscription is created on every update. To avoid firing an effect on
>   every update, refer to the next section.

---

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
>   unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
>   tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
>   or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
>   case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
>   works.

Comment: Your' right, it's cleaner now with `useEffect(() => {
    authGetUser(usr => setUser(usr));
    return authUnsubscribe;
  }, [])`, thanks. However, I still get the error in the console...

Comment: See the edit that I did on my answer. Try doing something like this: `setUser(null);` before unsubscribing

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this happens when we have asynchronous requests and the component is unmounted before, occurring memory leak. Obviously, that this not occur in class-based components because we have `componentDidMount()` and `componentWillUnmount()` hooks, so it's more confident than `useEffect()` that we have manipulated the state, so I think that you need to identify the reason for the application unmount and there is the solution.

**You should use one `useEffect()` instead two like this:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
  authGetUser(usr => setUser(usr))
  return authUnsubscribe() // runs on mount and unmount only
}, [])
```